# Hostname won't resolve correctly if apache ServerName isn't localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, centos, ssl

We have a lamp centos 7 server in a datacenter, behind some sort of a Nginx proxy. We only have control over our centos server, we don't know anything about the proxy/firewall or anything. We have installed SSL.

In `httpd.conf`, `ServerName`, the one that is not in `<VirtualHost>`, line 97

if  `ServerName localhost` then the website loads correctly, HTTP only, you get this SSL error

```
 RSA certificate configured for example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

if `ServerName example.com` then SSL loads correctly but if you try to access it either over HTTP or HTTPS you get  access denied, just that, probably this error is from Nginx or something not sure

If we omit ServerName, line 97 we get

`httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name`

The datacenter support says

> We tested port 80 & 443 for the server and they are open; it looks like a web configuration issue.

Comment: `ServerName` must match the name in the SSL certificate. The hostname of the server is irrelevant. `Access Denied` is a different issue, you need to provide the relevant configuration parts to get help with this.

Comment: You can ignore the warning about "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name". You have to fix the ServerName as @GeraldSchneider has mentioned. Then you can work on fixing the other error.

Answer (score 0):

Servername must match with the common name of the ssl certificate. Regarding access denied error you need to provide the correct document path that must have the complete rights to access.